# how can I receive data from Api by parts?

Tags: ios, swift, api

I have to read the file from API, but its size is about 1.6 MB, and it takes a long time. How can I read it by parts of 21 bytes?
Received data: [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSSbb.png)
I have this code, which read all file:

```
func getLogBinData() {
    if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                print()
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I tried next code, but delegate method don't work. Why?
I adding button, which print in console task.countOfBytesReceived, and it works well
code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    var task = URLSessionDataTask()

    var httpString = "here ip dress of my API"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getLogBinData()
    }


    func getLogBinData() {
        if let url = URL(string: httpString + "log.bin") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {
        if dataTask.countOfBytesReceived >= 20 {
            print(dataTask.countOfBytesReceived)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can't control how big each chunk of data is where they arrive. They can be 1 byte, or 4KB. But coming back to your question: what do you want to do as you receive each chunk of data?

Comment: @CodeDifferent, when I receive chunk and it's count more than 21 byte, I compare every 21 byte of it with my data, which storage inside app, if it's different, I add it to my storage data, and if its equal, I will stop receiving data

Comment: Your intention is still very unclear to me. Do you want divide the data you have received so far into blocks of 21 bytes and if there are 2 identical blocks, then stop receiving more data?

Comment: @CodeDifferent, no. Okay. every 21 bytes of this data describe states of sensor, and inside application I have logs(data about state of sensor in time), and when I launch application, I will to update my logs. I will receive data, and if it's new, i add it to my logs. when I receive data, which storage yet, I will stop. it's means, what with every launch i update my logs.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the URLSession delegate methods to monitor the receive progress of the download/request.

- [URLSessionDataDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate)
- [URLSessionDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate)

These protocols contain methods like [func urlSession(URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive: Data)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondatadelegate/1411528-urlsession) which will pass you the received data chunks as they come in.

You will need to keep track of how much data you have received and parsed, once you have a new amount of data >= 21 bytes you can append it to your data and read the next packet.

Comment: can you write code inside delegate methods and edit my method? because I don't understand how it must looks

Comment: This article shows how to set it up to use the delegate and receive and append data: http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/How-to-implement-NSURLSession-delegate-using-SWIFT

Comment: in what way? what have you done and what isn't working?. update your question with current code and explain updated issue

Comment: I don't know which method need to use, I try URLSessionStreamTask, but don't understand how it works. I need some code, which can receive data by parts of 21 byte

Comment: you cannot specify i want to receive it in 21 byte parts I don't think. you receive the data in chunks as standard. You need to use the functions I mentioned in my answer and keep track of how much data you have received so far. as long as you have more than or equal to 21 bytes you can read 21 bytes. It's similar to pagination. you have x number of bytes (pages) but you only want to read one page at a time. I dont have time to write it atm, maybe someone will come with an example for you